# angularjs custom directive passing string attribute for templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive as follows and I want to be able to pass the templateUrl in a custom directive

```
<div ng-if="box.key === 'experiences'" 
   experiences-form
   template-url="'experiences.php'" // template url I am trying to pass
   item="item"
   forms="forms"
   form-name="{{box.key}}{{item._id}}"
   onsave="updateMultipleUser(box.key, item._id, $data)"
   cancel="formAction($formName, 'cancel')"
   >
</div>
```

DDO for directive

```
{
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        onsave: '&',
        cancel: '&',
        formName: '@',
        forms: '=',
        item: '='
    },
    controller: controller,
    templateUrl: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
        return tAttrs.templateUrl; // returns 'experiences.php' how to get rid of the single quotes?
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok I got them to work by deleting them it was not working the first time I tried that for some reason, I thought if did not put the single quotes it will try and look for a $scope.experiences.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you putting the quotes in the templateUrl attribute? 
It should work just like that:

```
<div ng-if="box.key === 'experiences'" 
   experiences-form
   template-url="experiences.php" // template url I am trying to pass
   item="item"
   forms="forms"
   form-name="{{box.key}}{{item._id}}"
   onsave="updateMultipleUser(box.key, item._id, $data)"
   cancel="formAction($formName, 'cancel')"
   >
</div>
```

If it doesn't work, could you copy and paste the error message or the result you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return tAttrs.templateUrl.replace(/^'|'$/g,"")
```

Although it is recommended to remove these single quotes in `template-url="'experiences.php'"` or where you are creating